# Run a method for 5 sec

Tags: java, android

I would like to run a method every 1 ms in a timespan of 5 sec.
Right now i am using

```
long t = System.currentTimeMillis();
long end = t + 5000;
while (System.currentTimeMillis() < end) {
    // do something
    // pause to avoid churning
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The problem with this code is that it freezes the UI in the 5 sec timespan. Which I'm not interested in. Can a runnable or handler be used instead, and then terminated after 5 sec ?
Regards!

Comment: In addition to the solution below with Handler, spawining off a separate thread to do this would also have worked.  Or using a kotlin coroutine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Handler#postDelayed`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler#postDelayed(java.lang.Runnable,%20long)) recursively:

```
private void doTask(long endTimeMillis) {

    // do something

    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
    if (now < endTimeMillis) {
        new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(() -> {
            doTask(endTimeMillis);
        }, 1L);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate your time!